# Row wise operation on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, loops

**I want to iterate through the data frame and assign value in new column "**Minor-1**" where each value satisfy certain conditions.**

**INPUT DATA :**

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'Major' : ['A112','A112','B113','B113','B113','C114','C114','C114','C114'],'Minor' : ['X','Y','X','Y','Z','X','Y','Y','Z']}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
    {'Major': {0: 'A112', 1: 'A112', 2: 'B113', 3: 'B113', 4: 'B113', 5: 'C114', 6: 'C114', 7: 'C114', 8: 'C114'},'Minor': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'X', 3: 'Y', 4: 'Z', 5: 'X', 6: 'Y', 7: 'Y', 8: 'Z'},'Minor-1': {0: 'Start', 1: 'X', 2: 'Start', 3: 'X', 4: 'Y', 5: 'Start', 6: 'X', 7: 'X', 8: 'Y'}}
```

Input Data Looks like : [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2sVW.png) , Desired output looks like : [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKuNL.png)

Code I am using currently:

```
    df["Minor-1"]="Start"
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if df['Major'][i]==df.loc[i-1,'Major']:
            if df['Minor'][i]!=df.loc[i-1,'Minor'] :
                df.loc[i,"Minor-1"]=df['Minor'][i-1]
            else:
                df.loc[i,"Minor-1"]=df.loc[i-1,"Minor-1"]
```

Currently I'm doing it using for loop which I know is not time efficient at all. Which is the fastest way to perform this action?
I checked **iterrows** and **np.select** but couldn't figure out how to get desired output with those methods.

Comment: Please do not use images. Provide part of your actual data frame instead (as code) so that one can just copy-paste it. You can use `df.to_dict()` and copy the ouput. If your data frame is large, just use `df.head(10).to_dict()`. Also, please provide your desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your input @ko3
I am new to the community so learning.

Comment: Question: What happens if the `Minor`-values of a `Major`-block _start_ with 2 identical values, i.e. `X, X`? Is `"Start"` then propagated?

Comment: Yes ,  *Minor-1* will be "Start" for such case.
https://imgur.com/a/AYIbvHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another suggestion:

```
df["Minor-1"] = df["Minor"].shift()
df.loc[df["Minor"] == df["Minor"].shift(), "Minor-1"] = None
df.loc[df["Major"] != df["Major"].shift(), "Minor-1"] = "Start"
df["Minor-1"] = df["Minor-1"].ffill()
```

The [shifted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) column `Minor` is used as base for the new column `Minor-1`. The new column is then adjusted by:

- The positions where a value in `Minor` is the same as the prior one are set to `None`: preparation for the [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) application.
- The positions in which in column `Major` the values switch are populated with `"Start"`.
- Finally `.ffill()` fills the gaps.

---

I've done some performance measurement with a bigger dataframe:

```
from timeit import timeit

def test_1(df):
    df["Minor-1"] = "Start"
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df['Major'][i]==df.loc[i-1,'Major']:
            if df['Minor'][i]!=df.loc[i-1,'Minor'] :
                df.loc[i,"Minor-1"]=df['Minor'][i-1]
            else:
                df.loc[i,"Minor-1"]=df.loc[i-1,"Minor-1"]    

def test_2(df):
    df["Minor-1"] = df["Minor"].shift()
    df.loc[df["Minor"] == df["Minor"].shift(), "Minor-1"] = None
    df.loc[df["Major"] != df["Major"].shift(), "Minor-1"] = "Start"
    df["Minor-1"] = df["Minor-1"].ffill()

data = {
    'Major' : ['A112', 'A112', 'B113', 'B113','B113', 'C114', 'C114', 'C114', 'C114'],
    'Minor' : ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = pd.concat(df for _ in range(100)).reset_index(drop=True)

t1 = timeit("test_1(df)", globals=globals(), number=100)
t2 = timeit("test_2(df)", globals=globals(), number=100)

print(t1, t2)
```

Result: `t1 = 37.15364322599635` and `t2 = 0.5278295389944105` which seems quite an improvement to me.

Comment: @Tihom_Rahtus: Have you tested my most recent update (a couple of minutes ago)?

Comment: Output is correct however it takes more time than the current method.

I tried the below code, which also gives the desired output but takes more time than the current code.

`df['Minor-2']=df['Minor'].shift().where(df['Major']==df['Major'].shift(),"Start")` 

`df['Minor-2']=df['Minor-2'].shift().where((df['Major']==df['Major'].shift()) & (df['Minor']==df['Minor'].shift()),df['Minor-2'])`


Appreciate your help @Timus

Comment: @Tihom_Rahtus: See my update, I've also done some measurement, but with a bigger dataframe (small ones are not representative).

Comment: Yes, It is pretty fast when compared to the for-loop-code when performed on bigger data frame.